# Explain why catastrophic cancellation happens

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, catastrophic-cancellation

After my own research, the following picture emerges as the most frequently used example of catastrophic cancellation (It is indeed used in my class).

---

[image]

---

Could anyone explain why the plot takes that shape? (i.e., the widely fluctuating jagged line to the sides, and the vertical drop near the middle)

Minor point: why does the demonstrating function divides by $x^2$? Isn't $1 - \cos(x)$ enough to cause catastrophic cancellation?

Comment: If you plot $1 - \cos x$ over the same range of $x$, you won't see the cancellation because it is of order $x^2$ around the origin.

Comment: Lest anyone suspect, as i did, that this was an artifact of the plotting program used, here's the same weird result coming from (what I hope is) a completely different plotting program: http://a.pomf.se/inobme.png

Comment: [This related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986754/for-what-values-of-x-is-the-assignment-y-1-cos-x-problematic-and-why?rq=1) seems to suggest that under some conditions the same problem *can* occur with $1-\cos x$.

Comment: I suspect the machine wanted to punish you for having used Comic Sans. ;-)

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in R.  This supports the idea that this is an issue with floating-point numbers.

Comment: @MichaelLugo I know that this is a floating-point problem (indeed, the name is "catastrophic cancellation" -- it's not a name I make up). I was asking SE to help me understand this known problem.

Comment: At present, rounding is the only feasible way to compute with, say, large matrices over the reals (e.g. matrix-matrix multiplication, solution of large linear systems). From this perspective, it is not a problem or an issue, but a solution to a problem that happens to have side-effects. The example $(1-\cos(x))/x^2$ is meant to illustrate one of those.

Comment: [Wolfram|α does exactly the same thing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-cos%28x%29%29%2Fx**2+from+-4e-08+to+4e-08).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When $\cos(x)$ is computed for a reasonably small $x$, a number like 0.99999999999994598649857etc is obtained; the IEEE double precision standard defines a way to round this number to roughly 16 decimals. Thus out comes something like 0.99999999999995. I didn't count the digits, but you get the idea (and anyway, rounding is done in base 2). This does not seem catastrophic. But now subtract 1 from both numbers, and you see that a huge *relative error* has been committed to that result. The division by $x^2$ roughly gives you this relative error, because when $x$ is small, then $\cos(x) \approx 1 - \frac12 x^2$ (according to [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)). So when $x$ is very small, $\cos(x)$ is rounded to 1 (no digits after the comma), which explains the plateau in your plot.

Follow up on OP's request:
To formalize this, let $fl$, for "floating point arithmetics", be the function that rounds a real number to the nearest machine number ($=$ a number representable as double precision IEEE number, of which there are only finitely many). Although maybe not strictly accurately speaking (there may be optimization; there may be hidden extended precision computation; and the rounding is not always to the nearest machine number), the machine  computes not $(1 - \cos(x)) / x^2$ but 
$$
fl(
fl(
1 - {\color{red}{fl}}(\cos(x))
)
/
fl(x^2)
)
,
$$
supposing we start with $x$ such that $x = fl(x)$.
The issue originates with the application of the $fl$ that is marked in red, because
$$
{\color{red}{fl}}(\cos(x))
=
\cos(x)
(1 + \delta)
$$
where $|\delta| \leq \text{eps} \approx 10^{-16}$, 
and $\text{eps}$ is the smallest positive number such that
$$
fl(1 + \text{eps}) \neq 1
.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
1 - {\color{red}{fl}}(\cos(x))
=
1 - \cos(x) + \delta \cos(x)
\approx
\tfrac12 x^2 + \delta
$$
when $x$ is not too small (otherwise ${\color{red}{fl}}(\cos(x)) = 1$).
When $x$ is of order $\sqrt{\text{eps}} \approx 10^{-8}$ (as in your picture), this result $\tfrac12 x^2$ is contaminated by an absolute error of $\delta$, or a relative error of $2 \delta / x^2$. So the final result $(1 - \cos(x)) / x^2$ is contaminated by an absolute error of $\delta / x^2 \approx 1$ when $x \approx \sqrt{\text{eps}}$, which, again, is what you see in the picture.

ps.
There have been [infamous consequences](https://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/) of finite precision arithmetics.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the relative error? Plug in $\cos(x) \approx 1 - \frac12 x^2$ to $f(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x^2}$, I simply get $\frac{1}{2}$ when $x$ is small. What's the problem then?

Comment: @Heisenberg: see extended version

Comment: Isn't $1 - {\color{red}{fl}}(\cos(x))
=
1 - \cos(x) + \delta \cos(x)
\approx
\tfrac12 x^2 + \delta + \delta \frac{1}{2}x^2$? (note the last term). Are you removing it because multiplying $\delta$ and $x^2$ make it much smaller than the rest?

Comment: @Heisenberg: yes, significantly smaller in the regime considered